# How to reset my UIScrollView's position after returning from a modal transition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a simple view containing a long view with many buttons, with the whole thing being in a `UIScrollView`. The `scroller` works well, and I can `scroll` to the bottom and click a `button`. Every `button` triggers a modal `seque to` another `view`. That new `view` is then dismissed by user interaction, causing the original `UIScrollView's view` to load again.

Here's the problem: If I click on a button toward the top of the `UIScrollView`, I enter the modal `segue`, dismiss the new `view`, and return to the `UIScrollView's view` without a problem. But, if I click on one of the buttons toward the bottom of the `UIScrollView`, when I return `seque` out and then transition back, my scrolling is all messed up. I can only see the area *beneath* my `scroller`, and can't `scroll` back up to the top anymore!

I'm pretty sure there must be some way to reset the `UIScrollView's` starting and ending points upon `ViewWillAppear`, but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

Also, FYI, I simply added the `UIScrollView` through interface builder, and haven't implemented or synthesized it anywhere yet.

Comment: have you initalize your scroll view in view will appear ? , if yes then put that code in viewdidload as when you have dismissed a view its view will appear will call

Comment: Can you post up your current code or some screenshots of what it looks like before and after in the scenarios you are describing?

Comment: @IsaiahNelson It takes about 5 minutes to replicate, if you're interested. Create a new project with a storyboard. Initial `UIViewController` contains a long scrollview (tall enough to have to scroll) with a label at the top and a button at the bottom triggering a segue to a second VC. The second VC has a button that has an action that dismisses the second VC (that's the only line of code you'll need to write to repro this). Run in simulator. Scroll down. Click the first button. Click the second button. Boom - you can no longer scroll up to the top of the `UIScrollView` in the first VC.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

try this code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [yourscrollview setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Swift3: yourscrollview.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)

Answer (score 4):

### Please note: the bug this question and answer is about appears to be fixed in iOS 7. The rest of this answer is only relevant to iOS 6 (and probably earlier).

The behaviour being exhibited here is a bug in the `UIScrollView` class. As noted by the OP, after returning from a modally presented `UIViewController` to a scene containing a `UIScrollView`, the `UIScrollView` takes whatever point it's currently scrolled to and starts behaving as though that is its origin. That means that if you'd scrolled down your scroll view before modally presenting another View Controller, you can't scroll back up upon returning to the scene with the scroll view.

The same thing happens when you remove the Scroll View from the view hierarchy and re-add it, even without changing its window.

You can work around this by setting the `contentOffset` of the scroll view back to `{0,0}` before it gets displayed again after dismissing the modal View Controller. If you actually want to preserve the point the user had scrolled to before they triggered the modal, then *after* the `UIScrollView` is redisplayed you can set the `contentOffset` back to whatever it was before you reset it.

Here's a `UIScrollView` subclass that fixes the bug without resetting the scroll view to the top whenever you return from a modal:

```
@interface NonBuggedScrollView : UIScrollView

@end

@implementation NonBuggedScrollView {
    CGPoint oldOffset;
}

-(void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow {
    oldOffset = self.contentOffset;
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);
}

-(void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview {
    oldOffset = self.contentOffset;
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);
}

-(void)didMoveToWindow {
    self.contentOffset = oldOffset;
}

-(void)didMoveToSuperview {
    self.contentOffset = oldOffset;
}

@end
```

If you'd rather do this in a `UIViewController` than in a `UIScrollView` subclass, change the content offset in the `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear` methods.

If you don't want to preserve where the user's scroll position when they return from a modal, and just want to scroll the `UIScrollView` back to the top, as the OP asked for, then all you need is the even simpler:

```
@interface NonBuggedScrollView : UIScrollView

@end

@implementation NonBuggedScrollView

-(void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow {
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);
}

-(void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview {
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);
}


@end
```

Answer (score 4):

First, thanks for the approved answer above.  Someone mentioned that it was no longer applicable but I have a scrolling view inside of table view cell and it needs to be reset when the cell is reused.

Here is the solution in Swift.

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

// many lines of code later inside a function of some sort...

scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0), animated: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem i use this code:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.scrollview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)
                                animated:NO];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the starting and ending points by calling [scrollRectToVisible:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/scrollRectToVisible%3aanimated%3a). But I'm not sure if this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snippet to restore the scroll position for a UIScrollview

Declare "scrollPosition" variable as CGPoint type.

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    //get the current offset
    scrollPosition = scrollView.contentOffset;

    //set current view to the beginning point
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews 
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    //retrieve the previous offset
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = scrollPosition;
}
```

Comment: What if we using navigationcontroller?

Comment: @GajendraKChauhan : above code will work with NavigationController